# References to study the value of convergence of series and complicated integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, reference-request, definite-integrals

I have already studied criteria to study the convergence of series such as the ratio test, root test, comparison test, absolute convergence test, Leibniz test, condensation test, Cauchy test (and so on) according to the (common?) curriculum related to the first years of studies in mathematics undergraduate courses. However I have not been taught how to actually determine the value of convergence when the series meets one of these tests.

Having said that, could anyone suggest me introductory books or references so that I could study the convergence of such series as well as how to compute complicated integrals?

Comment: These seem to me to be two different requests

Comment: Evaluation is very different from determining convergence. Fourier analysis will be helpful sometimes. There is a Springer UTM text called really hard series and integrals ... something along those lines, I don't remember the exact name.